# Sequence of log-normal distributed random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-variables, independence

Let $X_1, X_2..$ be a sequence of independent log-normally distributed random variables. Prove that there exists a constant $c\in\mathbb{R} $ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i} = c\space\space\space[\mathbb{P}]$$

Comment: What happens if you take logs?

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen If we take log under the limit we will get a sample average of normally distributed random variables, which will converge by WLLN. But limit seems tricky.